# Create variable from print_r output

Tags: php

How can i create variable from it's print_r output ? In other words, i'd like to know if something similar to my fictive `var_import` function exists in php ? `var_import` would be the inverse of `var_export`

He is a use case:

```
$a = var_import('Array ( [0] => foo [1] => bar )');
$output = var_export($a);
echo $output; // Array ( [0] => foo [1] => bar )
```

If such a function does not exist, is there a tool (or online tool) to do this ?
I am also interested to do the same with `var_dump` output.

**EDIT: The variable is only available as a print_r output (string).** To clarify what i need, imagine the folowing situation: someone posts a some sample on the internet somewhere with a print_r output. To test his code, you need to `import` his print_r variable into your code. This is an example where `var_import` would be usefull.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/bg/function.var-export.php

Comment: You'll basically want to use the evil `eval`.

Comment: So you already know about `var_export`. But can you actually influence the input, or do you really need to reparse the print_r structure? Is so, a regex could work. But only reliably if newlines have been preserved or no nested arrays are present.

Comment: There is no way you can properly parse `print_r` output back to an array, object, etc. It is not structured enough for that (i.e.: too human friendly).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Amusingly the PHP manual contains an example that tries to recreate the original structure from the print_r output:
`print_r_reverse()`
 http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php#93529

However it does depend on whitespace being preserved. So you would need the actual HTML content, not the rendered text to pipe it back in.

Also it doesn't look like it could understand anything but arrays, and does not descend. That would be incredibly difficult as there is no real termination marker for strings, which can both contain newlines and `)` or even `[0]` and `=>` which could be mistaken for print_r delimiters. Correctly reparsing the print_r structure would be near impossible even with a recursive regex (and an actual parser) - it could only be accomplished by guesswork splitting like in the code linked above.. (There are two more versions there, maybe you have to try them through to find a match for your specific case.)

Comment: +1 if for no other purpose than resetting an unjustified downvote.

Comment: Yes, it works fine: http://codepad.org/L089YbgZ

Answer (score 10):

Why don't you use [`var_export`](http://php.net/var_export) instead ?

```
var_export(array(1, 2, 3)); // array(1, 2, 3)
```

You can *import* var_export's output with eval(), however I would recommend you to avoid this function as much as possible.

The following functions are better for *exporting* and *importing* variables:

[`serialize()`](http://php.net/serialize) and [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/unserialize):

```
$string = serialize(array(1, 2, 3));
$array = unserialize($string); // array(1, 2, 3);
```

Or [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode) and [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_encode):

```
$string = json_encode(array(1, 2, 3));
$array = json_decode($string);
```

Comment: I want to create my variable from the output (i don't have the variable before that). So i have `Array ( [0] => foo [1] => bar )`, not `array('foo', 'bar')`

Comment: But why don't you use something other than print_r in the first place ? print_r()'s output is not meant to be parsable / importable.

Comment: None of your suggestions answers the **actual** question. The print_r input is the precondition, not an option.

Comment: I was in the impression that he was wrongly using print_r for serializing purposes

Comment: I've been looking for something like this because people frequently put `print_r` output in SO questions, and I want to turn it into test data when I'm working on an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap it in an output buffer:

```
ob_start();
print_r(array(1,2,3));
$arr = ob_get_clean();
echo $arr;
```

Ok so I misunderstood the first question. I think I have another solution which actually does answer your question:

```
<?php
$ar = array('foo','bar');
$p = print_r($ar, true);

$reg = '/\[([0-9]+)\] \=\> ([a-z]+)/';
$m = preg_match_all($reg, $p, $ms);

$new_ar = $ms[2];

echo "Your wanted result:\n";
print_r($new_ar);
```

Comment: print_r() has a second parameter that does exactly this ;)

Comment: That's not what he wants. He basically wants to create an array previously exported with `print_r`. Besides, there's no need for output buffering in your example. Just do `$arr = print_r(array(1,2,3), true);`.

Comment: Ah now I get the question. Then I would definitely go for serialization.

Comment: Your pattern has 3 too many escaping slashes -- only the first is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import a [var_export()](http://php.net/var_export)'s variable, you can run the [eval()](http://php.net/eval) function.
Or if you save the contents into a file (with a return statement), you can use the return value of [include()](http://php.net/include) or [require()](http://php.net/require).

But I would rather use [serialize()](http://php.net/serialize) and [unserialize()](http://php.net/unserialize) or [json_encode()](http://php.net/json_encode) and [json_decode()](http://php.net/json_decode).

```
define('EXPORT_JSON', 1);
define('EXPORT_SERIALIZE', 2);

function exportIntoFile($var, $filename, $method=EXPORT_JSON)
{
  if ( $method & EXPORT_JSON )
    file_put_contents( $filename, json_encode($var) );
  else if ($method & EXPORT_SERIALIZE)
    file_put_contents( $filename, serialize($var) );
}
function importFromFile($filename, $method=EXPORT_JSON)
{
  if ( $method & EXPORT_JSON )
    return json_decode( file_get_contents($filename) );
  else if ($method & EXPORT_SERIALIZE)
    return unserialize( file_get_contents($filename) );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not good at regex to code the final trash removal. [Here](http://codepad.org/ufVhp72s) is how far I could get though:

```
$str = 'Array ( [0] => foo [1] => bar [2] => baz)';
$t1 = explode('(', $str);
$t2 = explode(')', $t1[1]);
$t3 = explode(' => ', $t2[0]);
unset($t3[0]);

print_r($t3);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => foo [1]
    [2] => bar [2]
    [3] => baz
)
```

Comment: What a downvote with no comment is supposed to mean?

Comment: Obviously with the above if the delimiters (`(`, `)`, and `=>`) also occur in the original array elements we'd be screwed. But this type of code is usually not expected to be very robust anyway.