# how to convert a text into an associative array?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi this is the code i am following in my project.

```
$reports = $this->curl->simple_get('url');
echo is_array($reports)?"Is Array":"Not Array";exit;
```

It's giving `Not Array` as output.

I want to convert that into associative array.

Comment: What is the output of `$report`?

Comment: when i tried to print using print_r($reports); It's huge data but i will post some data here in my question......

Comment: hope it's typping error ($reports != $report) :))

Comment: can you show what's the value of $reports (or give the url) ?

Comment: when i tried to print using print_r($reports) this is what i am getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you are getting is probably not an array, but a string containing an array structure, e.g. output by print_r(). This kind of data will not automatically be converted back into a PHP array.

To use this you can use a similar solution as brought out here: 
[Create variable from print_r output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231763/create-variable-from-print-r-output)

it describes the `print_r_reverse` function that's brought out in php.net page.

how ever - this is kind of an ugly hack. I would suggest to change the page content and use `json_encode()` in the "url" page, and parse the content using `json_decode()`

Comment: what-ever function you have that prints the array to the page, put the variable into a function. So instead of "print $array;" use "print json_encode($array);". At your page just use "json_decode($results);"

Comment: you are saying i need to encode the variable in controller file and decode in view file