# convert array to string and get it back to array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string

I'm using the Serialize function to store an array in my MYSQL database, and then I'm unSerialize Him in other page.
The array structure look like this :

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [names] => somename1 [rating] => 10 ) [1] => Array ( [names] => somename2 [rating] => 9 ) )
```

When I INSERT the array to the database I'm using this function to convert it to string :

```
$array_string=mysql_escape_string(serialize($arr));
```

And then, when I'm doing the unSerialize, **I don't know how to restore the string(array in the database) to the exactly structure that it was before. (how to convers this string back to array)**

I know I have to use this line :

```
$arr=explode("|",$list);
```

In some way, but I can't restore it to the exactly structure of the array it was before.
The result of this line is a little bit different in the structure of the array :

```
Array ( [0] => Array( [0] => Array ( [names] => d [rating] => 7 ) [1] => Array ( [names] => b [rating] => 6 )  ) )
```

Thanks

Comment: If you do know `serialize`, why you do not know `unserialize`?

Comment: @sectus +1. `unserialize()` will convert it back to a serialized string.

Comment: @sectus - my problem is to convert it back from the serialized string to array. I mentioned it.

Comment: @DavidAlexandrovich, so what is your problem? Did you try to use unserialize?

Comment: @sectus have a look, I have Highlighted (bold) the problem.

Comment: Could you show us original array, restored array with unserialize and the difference of it.

Comment: Can you post the serialized array as it goes into the DB and when it comes out of the DB.

Comment: @HermannStephaneNtsamo I'm doing this : "$array_string=mysql_escape_string(serialize($arr));" when I'm INSERT it to the database. 
And when it comes out I'm doing this : "$list=unserialize($query_row['list']);
            $arr=explode("|", $list);"

Comment: @DavidAlexandrovich, why you are using `explode`?

Comment: @sectus because I need to convert the string into array (after the unserialize). Anyone have a solution to this problem?

Comment: @DavidAlexandrovich you convert the serialized string to an array by using unserialize(). explode() is not needed here.

Comment: @Jens-AndréKoch OK, without explode its still not working. It's still a string :(

Answer (score 1):

The opposite of serialize is [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php).

```
$old_array = unserialize($serialized_array_string_from_db);
```

Storing values serialized into the database, disallows to query them individually.
You have to fetch the serialized value, unserialize and then you can start working with them.
This is not very efficient from a database design perspective. My suggestion is to create individual fields for "names" and "rating" in a extra table.

---

**Store Array serialized to Database**

```
$array = array('names' => 'somename1', 'rating' => 10);
$array_serialized_to_string = serialize($array);
doStoreToDb($array_serialized_to_string, somewhere);
```

**Fetch Serialized Array from Database**

```
$array_serialized_to_string = doFetchFromDb(somewhere);
$array = unserialize($array_serialized_to_string);
```

---

The difference in array structure might be the result from querying "the return set as array".
Just remove the outer array:

```
$old_array = unserialize($serialized_array_string_from_db);
$array = $old_array[0];
```

Comment: This is not my problem, I have Highlighted (bold) the problem.

Comment: you are right that I have to replace the $array = $old_array[0]; like this, but I think I didn't explain myself well.

Comment: The problem is - When I'm trying to get "echo $arr[0]['names'];" for example, I get warning : "Illegal string offset 'names' in bla bla bla.."
I think the problem is that $array is not recognized as array. because when I'm doing "echo $arr;" it's printing the arr like the print_r() function. I think it recognize it as a string.

Comment: Ok, let's take a look at the structure of the array and it's types: var_dump($arr)

Comment: array(1) { [0]=> string(505) "Array( [0] => Array ( [names] => d [rating] => 7 ) [1] => Array ( [names] => b [rating] => 6 ) [2] => Array ( [names] => a [rating] => 5 ) [3] => Array ( [names] => e [rating] => 5 ) [4] => Array ( [names] => c [rating] => 4 ) [5] => Array ( [names] => f [rating] => 3 ))" } 
By the way - Thank you man!

Comment: Now that's a bit weird. How did you create that?

Comment: I'm pushing it to the database this way : "$array_string=mysql_escape_string(serialize($arr));"
and then insert the $array_string

Comment: When I'm using the explode, this is the result :
array(1) { [0]=> string(422) "Array( [0] => Array ( [names] => e [rating] => 5 ) [1] => Array ( [names] => d [rating] => 4 ) [2] => Array ( [names] => c [rating] => 3 ) [3] => Array ( [names] => b [rating] => 2 ) [4] => Array ( [names] => a [rating] => 1 ))" }

Comment: This string gets a modification somewhere. Let's find out where. Please post a var_dump($array_string) directly after mysql_escape_string(serialize()). That should give us the serialized string before insertion into db. With adminer or phpmyadmin you should find exactly this string in your db. That's the insert part. Then: the fetching part. How do you query your db?

Comment: When I do vae_dump($array_string) directly after, I get this : string(350) "s:339:\"Array( [0] => Array ( [names] => d [rating] => 4 ) [1] => Array ( [names] => c [rating] => 3 ) [2] => Array ( [names] => b [rating] => 2 ) [3] => Array ( [names] => a [rating] => 1 ))\";"

Comment: $insert_into = "INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ('','$user_id','$list_name','$array_string') and then I run the query.

Comment: I think the $array_string should start with "a:(sizeOfArray):keys" and not "s:339..". Please var_dump($arr) before serialize (to make sure that is an array before serialization and not a string). Where is $arr coming from?

Comment: before the unserialize : string(339) "Array( [0] => Array ( [names] => d [rating] => 4 ) [1] => Array ( [names] => c [rating] => 3 ) [2] => Array ( [names] => b [rating] => 2 ) [3] => Array ( [names] => a [rating] => 1 ))"

Comment: I'm sending the array from the same page by a POST form, by this input : <input type="text" name="list" value='<?php print_r($arr); ?>' hidden>

Comment: ohh <input type="text" - is that the problem?

Comment: Ok, i think we found it! :) Your array isn't an array anymore, but a string, because of print_r... print_r gives you a string. then you are are serializing the string again..

Comment: It's a bit complicated to turn the string from print_r() back to an array, but possible, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231763/create-variable-from-print-r-output . In general it's better to use var_export($array, true), because the variable is easily converted back by a simple assign. - `<?php print_r($arr); ?>` this piece of code needs a change. if you simply removed print_r here, the form content looks ugly, but the serializing to array should start to work...

Answer (score 1):

Try `json_encode` and `json_decode`

```
$array_to_store = array(....);
$str_array = json_encode($array_to_store);
//Store $str_array
//Retrieve it and to make it an array again
$array = json_decode($str_array, true);

******************* Edited *********************
```

I do not see what is wrong with serialize and unserialize:

```
$array = array(
        array(
                'names' => 'somename1',
                'rating' => 10
             ),
        array(
                'names' => 'somename2',
                'rating' => 9
             )
    );

//Array before
print_r('<pre>');
print_r($array);

//Serialised Array
$s = serialize($array);

print_r('<pre>');
print_r($s);

//Unserialised Array
print_r('<pre>');
print_r(unserialize($s));
```